# How to print column values with pdo and make a link based on row id

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Im Trying to make an index of a certain value in my db.

I have a sqlite db with two columns of importance here; An id column named 'us_id' (auto increment), and a column with a text value in it named 'us_eq'.

my goal is to print out onto my site, the text value of every 'us_eq', as a link that directs to 'example.com/pages/[us_id]' for the corresponding id value.

Ex:

```
<a href="example.com/pages/[us_id]">[us_eq]</a>
```

Comment: I don't see any PDO logic here. Are you using any framework?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want all records you use the pdo oject like this

```js
$stm = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM YorTable');
$data = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then you just loop thru the rows, echoing the column values like

```js
foreach ($data as $row) {
   echo('<p><a href="example.com/pages/'.$row["us_id"].'">');
   echo($row["us_eq"].'</a></p>');
}
```